# integratable php blog API for existing site?

Tags: php, api, blogs

I'm inheriting a php project of a complete website. It's currently static; the owner just wants a blog on the front page to keep things fresh. Is there a mature PHP blog software out there that I can make a few calls to and have a blog up and running on their front page, without having to convert their entire existing site to a blog or CMS software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's one of the use cases for [Serendipity](http://www.s9y.org/). It has a configuration option specifically for that. So unlike Wordpress you don't need to hack it. It's not as featureful and a somewhat bloated package, but has a far better security track record.

http://www.s9y.org/123.html <- embedding howto

Comment: You shouldn't need to hack Wordpress very much to do it. It should be quite straint forward.

Comment: It seems to be doable with WP, but it looks a bit more involving: http://embedwordpress.com/ or http://moshublog.com/2005/07/05/integrate/ - so most people use an iframe or rather duplicate an existing site layout into a WP theme.